# Counting how many times a button was clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how can I count the number of times a button in my view was clicked using `sessions` and not using jQuery, just asp.net.

Here is my action method (empty) :

```
 public ActionResult ClickCounter()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and my view :

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "ClickCounter";
}

<h2>ClickCounter</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!-- form content here -->
    @Session["num"] = 0;
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Button clicks counter</legend>
            <div>
                <label for="Clciks">Clicks:</label>

               <h2>@Session["num"]</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Click!" class="submit" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
}
```

Excuse me for the lame questions, but I am a complete novice and trying to understand how this stuff work. I tried googleing.
I just want to display the click count in the h2 in my view using sessions for the purpose.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Currently `@Session["num"] = 0;` will reset the counter every time you view the page. Try putting `(int)Session["num"]++;` in your action method instead. You might need something to initialise the session value if it isn't already set, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is for simply increasing the clicked count on form submit, You can update your http post action method to read the session value if exist and increase and set it back. If not exist, initialize it.

```
const string sessionVariableName = "num";
public ActionResult ClickCounter()
{
   if (Session[sessionVariableName] == null)
   {
        Session[sessionVariableName] = 0;
   }
   return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClickCounter(string dummyParam)
{       
    if (Session[sessionVariableName] == null) // should not happen!
    {
        Session[sessionVariableName] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        var n = (int)Session[sessionVariableName];
        n++;
        Session[sessionVariableName] = n;
    }
   return View();
}
```

Make sure that you are doing a GET form method on submit.

You also need to remove the (re) initialization in the view this line `@Session["num"] = 0;` as we are doing that in the action method. Also you should not have nested forms as it is invalid. `Html.BeginForm` helper will render the markup for the form tag. So remove the inner form tag you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just dont get whe the count in Session[sessionVariableName] = count; comes from.

Comment: You also need to remove the (re) initialization in the view this line `@Session["num"] = 0;` as we are doing that in the action method.

Comment: yeah, i removed it. But basically when i press the button now it just adds a question mark to the url and says page not found.

Comment: what is the difference in the url before and after clicking submit ? It should be pretty much same (for controller name and action name)

Comment: Before : http://localhost:50916/Home/ClickCounter and after : http://localhost:50916/Home/ClickCounter?

Comment: is there a way to prevent the page refreshing every time i press this button? Also every time I refresh it manually the number increases without pressing the button.

Comment: If you want only that to happen in button submit, put that in your http post action method (see updated answer). If you do not want the page to referesh, use ajax to send the data, update the value in server and let the server return the updated number back and your ajax method's callback will use this response to update the DOM (h2)

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged this question as [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), why not take advantage of the framework?

**Model**

```
class MyModel
{
    public int ClickCount { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ClickCounter";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<form method="post">
    <!-- hidden input of the current click count -->
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClickCount) 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Button clicks counter</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClickCount)   
           <h2>@Model.ClickCount</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
const string clickCountSessionKey = "clickCount";
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ClickCounter()
{
    // initialize the model
    var model = new MyModel() { ClickCount = 0 };
    var previousClickCount = Session[clickCountSessionKey];
    if (previousClickCount != null)
    {
        model.ClickCount = (int)previousClickCount;
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClickCounter(MyModel model)
{
    // increment the click count of the model
    model.ClickCount++;
    // track the click count in the session
    Session[clickCountSessionKey] = model.ClickCount;
    return View(model);
}
```